# I need to click a button outside the ModalBottomSheet without dismissing the bottomSheet in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

## This is the function for the ModalBottomSheet

```
import ...

void ridePopUp(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref, Widget content, VoidCallback? onDone, bool actionVisible) {
  showModalBottomSheet(
    useRootNavigator: true,
    useSafeArea: true,
    enableDrag: false,
    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
    isScrollControlled: true,
    isDismissible: false,
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    barrierColor: Colors.transparent,
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return RideBottomPopupSheet(
        content: content,
        onDone: onDone,
        actionVisible: actionVisible,
      );
    },
  );
}

class RideBottomPopupSheet extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const RideBottomPopupSheet({
    super.key,
    required this.content,
    required this.actionVisible,
    this.onDone,
  });

  final Widget content;
  final VoidCallback? onDone;
  final bool actionVisible;

  @override
  ConsumerState createState() => _RideBottomPopupSheetState();
}

class _RideBottomPopupSheetState extends ConsumerState<RideBottomPopupSheet> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0)
            .copyWith(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom + 40),
        child: Container(
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(20),
            ),
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                    Radius.circular(20),
                  ),
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                width: double.maxFinite,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
                  child: widget.content,
                ),
              ),
              if (widget.actionVisible) ...[
                CustomContainer(
                  borderRadius: 0,
                  width: double.maxFinite,
                  child: TextButton(
                    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                      foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                      backgroundColor: Constants.primaryColor,
                    ),
                    clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                    onPressed: widget.onDone,
                    child: Text(
                      'Continue',
                      overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                      style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

## This is the Screen where there are two buttons at the top & a google map display.

```
class BookRideScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const BookRideScreen({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState createState() => _BookRideScreenState();
}

class _BookRideScreenState extends ConsumerState<BookRideScreen> {
  StateProvider<int> terminalSelected = StateProvider((ref) => 1);

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.edgeToEdge);
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      ridePopUp(
        context,
        ref,
        Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            /// FIRST CHOICE --> TERMINAL 1
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 18.0),
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  ref.read(terminalSelected.notifier).update((state) => 1);
                },
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Consumer(builder: (context, ref, child) {
                      return Checkbox(
                        value: ref.watch(terminalSelected) == 1 ? true : false,
                        materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.padded,
                        activeColor: Constants.primaryColor,
                        shape: const CircleBorder(),
                        side: const BorderSide(
                          width: 2,
                          style: BorderStyle.solid,
                          color: Color(0xffd9d9d9),
                        ),
                        onChanged: (bool? value) {
                          if (value == true) {
                            ref
                                .read(terminalSelected.notifier)
                                .update((state) => 1);
                          }
                        },
                      );
                    }),
                    Expanded(
                      child: ListTile(
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                        title: Text(
                          'Terminal 1',
                          style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                            fontSize: 18,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            color: const Color(0xff344054),
                          ),
                        ),
                        subtitle: Text(
                          'Pick Up Point',
                          style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                            fontSize: 12,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            color: const Color(0xff344054),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const Divider(
              color: Color(0xffd0d5dd),
              thickness: 1.8,
            ),

            /// Second Choice --> TERMINAL 2
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 18.0),
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  ref.read(terminalSelected.notifier).update((state) => 2);
                },
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Consumer(builder: (context, ref, child) {
                      return Checkbox(
                        value: ref.watch(terminalSelected) == 2 ? true : false,
                        materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.padded,
                        activeColor: Constants.primaryColor,
                        shape: const CircleBorder(),
                        side: const BorderSide(
                          width: 2,
                          style: BorderStyle.solid,
                          color: Color(0xffd9d9d9),
                        ),
                        onChanged: (bool? value) {
                          if (value == true) {
                            ref
                                .read(terminalSelected.notifier)
                                .update((state) => 2);
                          }
                        },
                      );
                    }),
                    Expanded(
                      child: ListTile(
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                        title: Text(
                          'Terminal 2',
                          style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                            fontSize: 18,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            color: const Color(0xff344054),
                          ),
                        ),
                        subtitle: Text(
                          'Pick Up Point',
                          style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                            fontSize: 12,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            color: const Color(0xff344054),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const Divider(
              color: Color(0xffd0d5dd),
              thickness: 1.8,
            ),

            /// THIRD CHOICE --> TERMINAL 3
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 18.0),
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  ref.read(terminalSelected.notifier).update((state) => 3);
                },
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Consumer(builder: (context, ref, child) {
                      return Checkbox(
                        value: ref.watch(terminalSelected) == 3 ? true : false,
                        materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.padded,
                        activeColor: Constants.primaryColor,
                        shape: const CircleBorder(),
                        side: const BorderSide(
                          width: 2,
                          style: BorderStyle.solid,
                          color: Color(0xffd9d9d9),
                        ),
                        onChanged: (bool? value) {
                          if (value == true) {
                            ref
                                .read(terminalSelected.notifier)
                                .update((state) => 3);
                          }
                        },
                      );
                    }),
                    Expanded(
                      child: ListTile(
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                        title: Text(
                          'Terminal 3',
                          style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                            fontSize: 18,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            color: const Color(0xff344054),
                          ),
                        ),
                        subtitle: Text(
                          'Pick Up Point',
                          style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                            fontSize: 12,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            color: const Color(0xff344054),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        () {},
        true,
      );
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual,
        overlays: SystemUiOverlay.values); // to re-show bars
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          const GoogleMap(
            initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
              target: GoogleMapsConstants.terminal1Location,
              zoom: 18,
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: MediaQuery.of(context).viewPadding.top,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    foregroundColor: const Color(0xff344054),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    shape: const CircleBorder(),
                  ),
                  child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/svgs/uyufjdx.svg'),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 5,
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    foregroundColor: const Color(0xff344054),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/svgs/gutdw.svg'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**I need to click those buttons and interact with the GoogleMaps with that ModalBottomSheet being opened. Since I need to open the ModalBottomSheet as soon as the screen opens, there isn't any chance to manually open the sheet using any button, it should open automatically when this screen opens & I should be able to interact with background screen content**

IMAGE: Design I need to implement

[image]

Comment: can you share the picture of the design you want?

Comment: @MunsifAli I've uploaded the image for the same. Kindly check

Comment: try `bottomSheet` property of the Scaffold widget hope this will work for you.

Comment: I tried implementing it using stack, using the same RideBottomPopupSheet widget. Thanks for the help

Comment: share the solution here. this might help others.